# Insert records into table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way in SQL SERVER(05 & 08) that I can insert records from an external file into a temp table? I do not have privilege to the database at all. Here is what i tried to do:

```
CREATE table #temp
(KEY_ID INT)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT 90883000
```

Ran #temp table with result:

```
KEY_ID
---------
90883000
```

It kind of works with just one record. How do I do if I have hundred records? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This just to show how to add multiple rows in a table.**

```
CREATE table #temp(
   KEY_ID integer
)

Declare @i as int

set @i = 1

WHILE  (@i <= 10000)
BEGIN

insert into #temp values(@i)

set @i += 1

End
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a table variable.  I believe that the #temp need rights to the tempdb database.  I believe that a table variable is used just like any other variable which is session based.

To declare a table variable:

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
(
  ProductID int,
  Revenue money
)
```

Insert into a table variable:

```
INSERT INTO @ProductTotals (ProductID, Revenue)
  SELECT ProductID, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
    FROM [Order Details]
    GROUP BY ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks all. The records i was trying to import into the temp are from outside of the database.

Answer (score 0):

For importing files, you can use **[BULK IMPORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)**. Use this to get the data into your temp table, then you can run set based operations against it.

---

A more effective way of inserting a lot of rows.

```
INSERT INTO #temp
(KeyID)
SELECT TOP 1000 -- PUT YOUR QUANTITY HERE
       IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
     Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2
```

If you're going to be using this a lot, just ask them to create you a **[TALLY TABLE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)**.

Comment: Thanks Brad. The records i was trying to insert are from outside of the database. So, not sure if this would works.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the file? Just how limited is your access?

Comment: I am trying to match the records that i want to insert into a temp tb with the records in the existing table. I could do something like this select key_id from table1 where key_id in(90883000, ..., ..., ...,...). This method works for a handfuls but not efficient when in hundreads). That's why I tried to create a temp to join with table1.

Comment: Match to update or to output to a different process? Have you tried using `BULKIMPORT` to get the records into temp table then matching with an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @Brad, I tried using Bulkimport method to get the records but no good due to - You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.
 Msg: 4834, Level: 16, State: 4, Procedure: , Line: 11

Comment: @Chris, how else are you getting the file into the sproc? If they want you to build something, they might actually have to give you the permissions you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it if I have the values in a file somewhere. Inserting hundreds of records from flat text file into temp table. My example only has one column, but as long as the flat file is delimited somehow, you can do as many columns as needed. Need to make sure you put the text file in a directory you have access to.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(Col1 varchar(10))   --Specify temp-table name & columns

    BULK INSERT #TempTable
       FROM 'C:\FileName.txt'           --Specify file path/name
       WITH (
         FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
       );
    GO
```